# Why UITableView cell overlap while scrolling?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with approx 100  row.

Each cell having checked image but when we scroll the `UITableView`, all the cells overlapped in unchecked cell.

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"Cell";
static NSString *MyIdentifierAds = @"Cell1";

UITableViewCell *cell ;

if (tableView==self.tblSeachMarketplace) {
    if (indexPath.section==0) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
 //            if(cell== nil)
 //            {
 //                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
 //            }

        UILabel* lblTitle = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:200];
        UILabel*lblSubheading = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:300];
        UIImageView* imgRating = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:400];
        UIImageView* imgLogo = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
        [lblTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Lato-Bold" size:12.5f]];
        [lblSubheading setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Lato-Bold" size:9.0f]];
        [lblTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Lato-Bold" size:12.5f]];
        [lblSubheading setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Lato-Bold" size:9.0f]];
        [lblTitle setTextColor:[Global colorFromHexString:@"#4394d4"]];
        NSDictionary*row=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor =  [UIColor whiteColor];
        if (allMarketPlaceNewsletters.count>0) {
            row=[allMarketPlaceNewsletters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSString *imgUrl=[row valueForKey:@"logo"];
            if (imgUrl != (id)[NSNull null]) {
                NSURL *urlTemp = [NSURL URLWithString:imgUrl];
                [imgLogo  setImageWithURL:urlTemp placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"]];
            }

            UIButton *btnLocationRight=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:600];
             UIButton *btnLocationPlus=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:500];

            if ([[row valueForKey:@"subscribed"] isEqualToString:@"Y"]) {
                [btnLocationRight setHidden:NO];
                [btnLocationPlus setHidden:YES];
                cell.contentView.backgroundColor =  [Global colorFromHexString:@"#f0f9fc"];
                [btnLocationRight setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"righbtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                 [btnLocationRight setTag:indexPath.row];
    //          [btnLocationRight addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
              //  [cell addSubview:[self buttonWithMap:cell :@"righbtn.png":indexPath.row]];
            }else{
                cell.contentView.backgroundColor =  [UIColor whiteColor];
                [btnLocationPlus setTag:indexPath.row];
                [btnLocationPlus addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                 [btnLocationPlus setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"darkplusbtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                [btnLocationRight setHidden:YES];
                 [btnLocationPlus setHidden:NO];
               // [cell addSubview:[self buttonWithMap:cell :@"darkplusbtn.png" :indexPath.row]];
            }

            NSString *stars=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",[[row valueForKey:@"rating"] intValue]];
            imgRating.image=[UIImage imageNamed:stars];

        }
```

Comment: Please provide some code, the `cellForRow` method at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very wrong... As I can see, you're creating your cell through interface builder. In that case, you create your custom `UITableViewCell` class for it, which will have `IBOutlets` to your `UILabels` and `UIImageViews` (and other UI elements you'd like). This will make sure your UI elements get created for you and you don't have to `alloc-init` and `addSubview` in your `cellForRow` method.

It would take fairly long to explain everything here, so you could take a look at [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702), it explains how to create custom `UITableViewCells` better then I could. Mainly `Option 2: Prototype Cells` is what you need.

Comment: Good advise, Thanks Lord. And your link is too helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Add this code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
NSArray *subviews = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:cell.contentView.subviews];
for (UIView *subview in subviews)
{
    if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    else if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    else if([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    else if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]])
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    else if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        [subview removeFromSuperview];

}
[subviews release];
```

Hope this will Help you.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you.If it works for you then please accept it so that it will help to other.:)

Comment: My vote is not counted becaz of I am new User in stack, and my reputation is low.

Comment: Woah woah woah... I really hope you're not using `addSubview` in your `cellForRow` method.