# UIimageview showing more than one time in uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview

i have a table in my application which is loading xml menu. and in which i placed a uiimageview for every cell as bullet image. but my problem is that first time table shows correct (one image in one cell) but when i scroll down further in the menu. it start showing images 3 time in a cell. i will post my code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"menuCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-bold" size:18];
    if ([[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmlid] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [cell setIndentationLevel:3];
        [cell setIndentationWidth:10];
        cellImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,cell.frame.size.height/2+5, 15, 15)];

    }else if ([[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmlid] isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [cell setIndentationLevel:6];
        [cell setIndentationWidth:10];
        cellImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35,cell.frame.size.height/2+5, 13, 13)];

    }else if ([[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmlid] isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [cell setIndentationLevel:9];
        [cell setIndentationWidth:10];
        cellImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65,cell.frame.size.height/2+5, 11, 11)];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmltitle];

    cellImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];
    [cell addSubview:cellImage];


    return cell;
}
```

and here is what is actually happening.
[image]

Comment: simply add the imageView in `cell == nil` and set a `tag` value to the image view. them get the image view using `viewWithTab:` then set the image view

Comment: did you tried my answer below

Comment: yes i did tried that one and it stopped repetition of arrows but now image is not showing where it should display i mean its frame not correct as i wanted  that i mentioned in if ([[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmlid] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {

Comment: what is `xmlid`? and why you are setting different `indentation level` and `indentation width`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `cellImage = nil;` as very first line in your method and your problem will get solved.

**Update :**

try to add cellImage in `contentview` of cell instead of cell like,

```
[cell.contentView addSubview: cellImage];
```

hope this will help :)

Comment: are you setting image in `didselectrow` also ?

Comment: same issue. Thanks

Comment: now you should make `customtabelview` class and add `imageview` from `awakeFromNib` method. don't add from `cellforrowatindexpath`. just change frame from this method. it may solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Double check your `cell identifier` in `storyboard` if your are creating `tableView` in Storyboard.

And Your Cells are being reused that's why you are seeing this behaviour.

Don't add you Image in Cell instead of add Image in ContentView.

```
   [cell.contentView addSubview:MyImageView];
```

Comment: tabelview is programmatically created in a sub view which i am using as menu of self.view

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118286/why-uitableview-cell-overlap-while-scrolling

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28556172/text-get-overlapped-while-scrolling-in-ui-table-view

Answer (score 0):

Because of this line

```
[cell addSubview:cellImage];
```

When you scroll, cellForRowAtIndexPath is called, and an image view is added to your table view cell.

To resolve this, there's some solution:

- Write your custom cell class, init image view once in layoutSubViews,
  and only change image content in cellForRowAtIndexPath.
- Create image view in custom cell xib and add outlet to your custom
  cell class

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this code,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"menuCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        UIImageView *cellImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [cellImage setTag:100];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:cellImage];
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-bold" size:18];

    if ([[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmlid] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [cell setIndentationLevel:3];
    [cell setIndentationWidth:10];
    [cellImage setFrame:CGRectMake(5,cell.frame.size.height/2+5, 15, 15)];

}else if ([[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmlid] isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [cell setIndentationLevel:6];
    [cell setIndentationWidth:10];
    [cellImage setFrame:CGRectMake(35,cell.frame.size.height/2+5, 13, 13)];

}else if ([[[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmlid] isEqualToString:@"3"]) {
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [cell setIndentationLevel:9];
    [cell setIndentationWidth:10];
    [cellImage setFrame:CGRectMake(65,cell.frame.size.height/2+5, 11, 11)];
}

    cell.textLabel.text = [[rssOutputData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]xmltitle];

    cellImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i even triend by commenting this part " UIImageView *cellImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];" in cell == nill but after that again repetitions n all

Comment: see i dint add `cellImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35,cell.frame.size.height/2+5, 13, 13)];
` each time i just set the frame that is what the problem for you `[cellImage setFrame:CGRectMake(65,cell.frame.size.height/2+5, 11, 11)];`

Comment: each time you are allocating a new UIImageView and added it to the cell so only multiple image views are appering

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
cell.clipsToBounds=YES;
```

Answer (score -1):

Allocate `imageView` one time and give `tag` to the `imageView` and use that tag to show image and
use:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:MyImageView];
```

and your problem will be solved